# how to find maximum edge in the path for mst graph in r

Tags: r

```
    a             b             c           d           e
a   0.0           5.0           22.3606     586.9412    1041.3933
b   5.0           0.0           26.9258     591.8825    1045.143
c   22.3606       26.9258       0.0         565.6854    1019.8039
d   586.9412      591.8825      565.6854    0.0         632.455
e   1041.3933     1045.143      1019.8039   632.455     0.0
```

I'm new to R , and I am having problems finding the maximum edge distance for a minimum spanning tree graph with this sample dataset. My code is below. I don't know how to proceed further for finding the maximum edge distance in the path for each vertex.

```
library(cluster)
library(igraph)
g <- read.table("C:/Users/VIVEK/Documents/R/Gap/samp.txt")
m <- as.matrix(g)
ig <- graph.adjacency(m, mode="undirected", weighted=TRUE)
plot(ig, edge.label=round(E(ig)$weight, 3))
mst <- minimum.spanning.tree(ig)
plot(mst,layout=layout.reingold.tilford,edge.label=E(mst)$weight)
```

Comment: What exactly is the result you want here? Do you just want the total length (sum of the edge weights) for `mst`?

Comment: i need to get maximum weighted  edge path for each node..

Comment: also i need,, how to construct subgraphs for the obtained mst..thanks

Comment: The path from where to where? There's just one minimum spanning tree. It's still unclear to me what you want.

Comment: here the my task is to derive pairwise distance to detect non spherical groups of clusters..so the pairwise distance between vertex is obtained by longest edge in the path joining a pair of points.. in my mst graph i need to find longest edge in the path..

Comment: can any one help me for how to select longest path for the obtained mst graph?? i.e for example a-c-d-e,,,   ..... thanks